# React & HashRouter - got blank pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

After I setted up routing on client side by `react-router-dom` all I got it's just blank empty pages.

[image]

So, my setup is here. I bet something is wrong but I can't get it.

So how come? What's wrong?

Index:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
    HashRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './containers/app.js';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import routes from './routes';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

Routes are here:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    HashRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './containers/app.js';
import Settings from './components/settings/settings.js';
import NotFound from './components/common/notfound';

export default (
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
        <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
)
```

Comment: Does anything load at `localhost:61958/` or is it just `localhost:61958/#/settings` that's not working?

Comment: which version of React Router are you using?

Comment: @MarioF probably the last one

Comment: @jolyonruss sorry for late answer - all links been lead to blank page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this section to:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
        <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

I don't think react-router v4 recognizes this part: `<Router routes={routes} />`

**Revised:**
There are two problems with the above codes.

1) You should not place a subroute inside a route. This part is incorrect:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App}>
  <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

2) `<NotFound />` is always rendered no matter what the path is.

**Solution:**

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
    HashRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
} from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './containers/app.js';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import routes from './routes';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("content")
);
```

App.js

Insert this codes to where you want to render the contents:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
   <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />
   <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Do not forget to add `import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: if you see the docs for `Route` (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func), you should not use the `component` prop and pass children to the route. You should actually have the routes all on the same level. Multiple matchings can occur, or you can use `Switch` if you want only one

Comment: @MarioF Agreed. The easiest way, those two routes should be included in the `App` class. I just copied and pasted his codes, thought that I modified that section as well he will be more confused. So let him try and make it work first ;)

Comment: oh, interesting, but what if I want it keep separately?

Comment: As @MarioF said above, your routes are "incorrect". First, you should not place subroutes inside a route. Second, the `<NotFound />` is always rendered no matter what the path is. You need to use `<Switch />`. Revising my answer right now.

Comment: oh, now it works! thank you. I use hashrouter cuz of I got asp.net core on server, faster then trying to deal with `browserHistory` in this case

Comment: No problem. React router v4 is so flexible, it has several different ways to achieve the same result. Above is the simplest way, though perhaps not the "best approach".